# create only file permission on linux

Tags: linux, file, file-permissions

I would like to create a directory under linux (or mount one e.g.: nfs), where:

1. every user can create files
2. but only the root user can modify the created files (overwrite, delete, or move them)

How can this be done, and how secure are these solutions?
(for example: sentinel script, umask, etc.?)

Thanks,
krisy

Comment: Not sure if this can be done, but if it can it probably involves ACLs, not traditional Unix permission modes.

Comment: Take a look at the SELinux kernel extension. It is standard and well supported by the major distributions. It allows very fine grained permission control, up to complete paranoida.

Comment: This doesn't really belong here, though you will definitely find people who can answer the question :) Try [su] or http://unix.StackExchange.com.

Comment: Will take a look at SELinux (or AppArmor), thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to change file permissions after creation using [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait). This (untested) snippet might help a bit, but is definitely not very elegant. It sets root as the owner of all created files in /path/to/dir and removes write-permission for group and others.

```
while true; \
    do inotifywait -e create /path/to/dir/ && \
    chown root /path/to/dir/* && \
    chmod g-wo-w /path/to/dir/*; \
done
```

Hope that helped a bit
*jost

Answer (score 0):

If it is also ok that the user that created the file can change them, you can use the sticky bit. This is the first digit if you give chmod a 4 digit argument.

```
su - 
mkdir stickydir
chmod 1775 stickydir
chown user.group stickydir
```

Now all members of group can write to the dir, but only the user that created a file or root can change the files

```
su - user1 #member of group
touch stickydir/stickytest-user1 #ok
su - user2 #member of group
touch stickydir/stickytest-user2 #ok
rm stickydir/stickytest-user1 #permission denied
rm stickydir/stickytest-user2 #ok
```

Comment: Just read about the sticky bit - very tricky, but unfortunately won't help me :-(